# Getting theMailchimp Member info with PHP/API with campaign EID

Tags: php, mailchimp

I am using the Mailchimp API for a few things successfully, one thing I want to do, but can not find the answer for, is using the `mc_eid`, request the members basic info ( first/last name, email ).

I can do it if I have the email address, but if I only have the `mc_cid` & `mc_eid` I have not found a way yet.

Am I missing something here. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're collecting data from ECommerce360 and hoping to link that up to a specific list subscriber. This will require two steps.

First, you need to find the list associated with the campaign ID. To do that, call the [campaigns/list](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/campaigns/list.php) call, supplying `mc_cid` as filter for campaign_id.

Once you have the `list_id` from the `campaigns/list` call, you can call [lists/member-info](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/member-info.php). You'll pass the `list_id` as the `id` parameter to that call, and then you'll pass the `mc_eid` as the `emails.euid` parameter.

To make this more efficient, you'll probably want to cache the campaign_id / list_id relation.

Comment: Thanks Pete, I'll have a go at this.